# How to exit mqtt forever_loop?

Tags: python, mqtt

I created a program to receive data, recently.

And I want to break the loop When I receive a specific data.

For example, if I receive "1" to another machine, then my system will regard it
as an illegal number, then it will break the loop to stop receiving data.

Here is my code in the below, and you can also see `client.loop_stop()` in my code. But it not works.

I have also tried `sys.exit()` in my code.

Although it works in this case, it is not suitable to be utilized in other situation.

So I am wondering about how to break the loop of the client, I don't want to close the whole system by  `sys.exit()`.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
# This is the Subscriber
a=""
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
  print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
  client.subscribe("hello")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    info=msg.payload.decode()
    print info
    if str(info)=='1':
      print "OK"
      client.loop_stop()


client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("myIp",1883,60)

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.loop_forever()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to stop `loop_forever`, you must use `client.disconnect`, not `loop_stop`.

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you, it will make it more clear for others down the line.

Answer (score 0):

*N.D.C. already answered this question correctly, but here is an answer with more details.*

According to the [Eclipse Paho MQTT Python client documentation](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#external-event-loop-support), since the last line of your script calls `loop_forever`:

> [`loop_forever`] is a blocking form of the network loop and will not return until the client calls disconnect(). It automatically handles reconnecting.

Therefore to exit from this blocking loop, you need your event handler to call `disconnect` (not `loop_stop`):

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    info=msg.payload.decode()
    print info
    if str(info)=='1':
      print "OK"
      client.disconnect()
```